# jQuery Mandatory Spaces?

Tags: jquery

Just wondering why the space is required here..

```
.load(url + (' #newsItem')
```

How exactly do I know when a space is needed and when it's not? Any good resources possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the space, jQuery wouldn't know `#newsItem` isn't part of the URL but the indication you want to load a page fragment.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

> **Loading Page Fragments**
>
> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> 1 $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
>
> When this method
>   executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery
>   parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of
>   container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the
>   element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document
>   is discarded.

Comment: thanks @dystroy it actually clicked from the first sentence. I was instantly reminded of my days of learning JavaScript always getting sentenced munched together because I had "a word" + "another word"